# Can a pager item point to an anchor on the page?

Tags: 7, paging

I'm building a page where, somewhere down in the middle of it, there's a pager of some stuff.  The pager is working fine, but, when you click on one of the pager items, the page is redrawn showing the top of the page, which usually does not include the (now updated) contents of the pager.  This is because the pager item URLs simply refer to the page as a whole.  Is it possible to get a reference to an anchor inserted into the URLs of the pager items, so that the browser will redraw the page with the pager contents in view?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [theme_pager_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_link/7) in Drupal 7. Your site's theme can customize any pager link by implementing `YOURTHEME_pager_link` and then add additional logic into a copied version of that function to embed anchors as needed.

You can probably embed the anchor as a `parameter` to the link to be inserted into the querystring:

> parameters: An associative array of query string parameters to append
>   to the pager link.

Comment: very interesting -- I'll check that out and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this does seem like the right area, but I can't figure out (nor find any refs to) how to get parameters into the MYTHEME_pager_link function. I can get a "fragment" anchor into the links produced by MYTHEME_pager_link, but I need to know what part of my code is making the pager, or I'll have the anchors attached to every pager on my site, which is obviously wrong. I could try to dissect the page's path from $_GET['q'] and do something based on that, but that's troublesome, and won't handle the case of two pagers on a page. So: tips on passing stuff into MYTHEME_pager_link? V. mysterious.

Comment: Dull ax approach, I would look at overloading the `$element` argument, eg, initially creating this paged content with that set to something not found elsewhere on your site (like some outrageous number like 228 or something) and then keying in on that here.

Comment: So, @Jimajamma, there's a DullAxes'R'Us near you, too? :)  I was thinking about that same thing -- setting $element to 100 or something -- but the URLs on the links got SO ugly (add one hundred "%2C1"s to the URL) that I had a temporary outbreak of taste, and couldn't do it.  But I may have to retreat to it, perhaps with a smaller value... :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @tenken although in the right direction, you don’t have any context within that function to target ONLY the comment pagers. Actually as far as I know you cannot only affect certain pagers period.

The way you could go about it is by using js, and target only the comment pagers:

```
// add js to insert anchor links to #comments in comment pagers
drupal_add_js("
  Drupal.behaviors.comment_pager_anchors = function (context) {
    var comment_pager_links = $('#comments .pager a');
    comment_pager_links.each(function(){
      this.href = this.href + '#comments';
    });
  }
", 'inline', 'footer');
```

You could add this for example within theme_pager, theme_pager_link, or in hook_nodeapi if you have comments for example.

Comment: note this comment is for Drupal 6... :s

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Manuel Garcia's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/95099/12010) I was able to make this work in **Drupal 7** with the following JavaScript:

```
Drupal.behaviors.pager_fragments = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    var pager_links = jQuery('#my-wrapper-id .pager a');
    pager_links.each(function(){
      this.href = this.href + '#myfragment';
    });
  }
}
```